# Schema for ACL/User/Group/Role management

Tags: schema, array

I'm building an app with some fairly complex permission and ACL rules and want to get my schema right.

These are my goals:

- A user signs up on behalf on an organization.
- Organization has groups. There can be any number of groups in an organization.
- A user can belong to one or more groups.
- An "Entity" can have an "ACL" record - this record indicates which users and groups can write to it, and which users and groups can read from it.

My current approach is to use PostgreSQL's arrays. So groups and organizations are simple tables with IDs and a foreign key.

**User Columns**

- `group_ids` - array of integers
- ...others

**Entity Columns**

- `writable_user_ids` - array of integers
- `writable_group_ids` - array of integers
- `readable_user_ids` - array of integers
- `readable_group_ids` - array of integers

But I'll have to do all queries on entities like:

`SELECT * FROM entity WHERE [<current id>] IN writable_user_ids OR [<group id list>] IN writable_group_ids;`

Is there a better way to do this? I am fairly certain there is since a lot of apps follow this pattern.

Comment: Have you considered using impersonation / proxy authentication?

Comment: Why use arrays for this? FK on array items were dropped for performance reason https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-9-3-development-array-element-foreign-keys/